# How to merge enumerated.pdf files in order by filename?

Tags: command-line, catalina

A set of enumerated pdf are in a directory:

```
1001_falcon.pdf
0100_bear.pdf
0201_cat.pdf
0201_cat.txt
```

The goal is to merge only the pdf files into output.pdf with a script.

[pdftk](https://www.maketecheasier.com/combine-multiple-pdf-files-with-pdftk/#combine-multiple-pdfs) is already installed and can merge pdf files

To merge two pdf files via pdftk, `file1.pdf` and `file2.pdf`:

```
pdftk file1.pdf file2.pdf cat output mergedfile.pdf
```

How would one merge the set of pdf files in the directory for pdftk to create mergedfile.pdf?  The goal is to have only the .pdf file merged in order:

```
0100_bear.pdf, 
0201_cat.pdf 
1001_falcon.pdf
```

If there is an simpler method to achieve the goal (preferably using a native MacOS command instead of pdftk), I look forward to your reply

Bonus round: a one-liner to merge in reverse order:

```
1001_falcon.pdf
0201_cat.pdf 
0100_bear.pdf,
```

Comment: Try [PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/commandline.html) instead. It requires Java, but it works much better

Comment: The link is broken, and the part starting with "pdftk merge syntax" is hard to understand. Also, it's not really clear whether you are looking for help with pdftk ("How would one pipe the set of pdf files in the directory for pdftk to create mergedfile.pdf" or whether you are looking for another tool.

Comment: What is wrong with running `pdftk *.pdf cat output mergedfile.pdf`?

Answer (score 0):

For simple concatenation of PDF files, the utility `pdfunite` is about as simple as it gets. It is one of the utilities that come with the [Poppler PDF rendering library](https://poppler.freedesktop.org/) and can be installed with `brew install poppler`. It is also included in the `poppler-utils` package in Debian and Ubuntu and the `poppler` package in ArchLinux and Fedora if you're using Linux.

The usage is

```
pdfunite file1.pdf file2.pdf file3.pdf mergedfile.pdf
```

To process all files with the extension "pdf" in the current directory in the order of string numerical value **if there are no whitespaces in any of the files**:

```
pdfunite $(\ls -v *.pdf) output.pdf
```

And if there are possibly whitespaces in the filenames, it gets a little more complicated, but this should work:

```
(\ls -v *.pdf; echo output.pdf) | tr \\n \\0 | xargs -0 pdfunite
```

Explanation:

- `\ls` invokes the `ls` from your `$PATH` ignoring any aliases. This may be important in case you have an aliased `ls` that shows extra information (like special characters to denote certain permissions). You can also just use an absolute path to the `ls` executable, like `/usr/bin/ls`.
- `ls -v` sorts the files according to (version) numbers within text
- `tr \\n \\0` replaces newlines with NULLs after each file
- `xargs -0` tells xargs to use the NULL character to separate arguments

As you can see, proper handling of things like whitespace (and other special characters) when piping commands in the shell can get a little complicated. If you'd like to read more, I recommend David Wheeler's [comprehensive article](https://dwheeler.com/essays/fixing-unix-linux-filenames.html).